# Mongoid Identity Map setting not taking effect in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid3

It does not appear that the [`identity_map`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html) setting is getting picked up from the `config/mongoid.yml` file.

Here's the file:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/test_development
      options: &defaultopts
        op_timeout: 60
        allow_dynamic_fields: false
        identity_map_enabled: true
        preload_models: true
        raise_not_found_error: false
```

When this is run through `RAILS_ENV=development rails console` the map is not turned on:

```rb
$ RAILS_ENV=development rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
[1] pry(main)> Mongoid.using_identity_map?
=> false
[2] pry(main)> Mongoid.identity_map_enabled?
=> false
```

Even an attempt to manually load `Mongoid` and the file doesn't change it:

```rb
[3] pry(main)> require 'mongoid'
=> false
[4] pry(main)> Mongoid.load!("./config/mongoid.yml")
=> {"sessions"=>
  {"default"=>
    {"uri"=>"mongodb://localhost:27017/test_development",
     "options"=>
      {"op_timeout"=>60,
       "allow_dynamic_fields"=>false,
       "identity_map_enabled"=>true,
       "preload_models"=>true,
       "raise_not_found_error"=>false}}}}
[5] pry(main)> Mongoid.using_identity_map?
=> false
[6] pry(main)> Mongoid.identity_map_enabled?
=> false
```

Only if I manually set the value does it take affect:

```rb
[8] pry(main)> Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = true
=> true
[9] pry(main)> Mongoid.using_identity_map?                                                                                                                                                                                                    
=> true
[10] pry(main)> Mongoid.identity_map_enabled?
=> true
```

Why is the setting not being loaded correctly?

This issue is happening using Rails 3.2.13 and Mongoid 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:options` shouldn't be nested in `:default`. Mongoid is expecting to see `mongoid.yml` in the format:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/test_development
  options:
    op_timeout: 60
    allow_dynamic_fields: false
    identity_map_enabled: true
    preload_models: true
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

See [source](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/config.rb#L130) where `:options` are being loaded.

```
 $ pry
 [1] pry(main)> require 'mongoid'
 => true
 [2] pry(main)> Mongoid.load!("./mongoid.yml", :production)
 => {"sessions"=>
    {"default"=>{"database"=>"mongoid_prod", "hosts"=>["localhost:27017"]}},
    "options"=>{"identity_map_enabled"=>true, "include_root_in_json"=>true}}
 [3] pry(main)> Mongoid.using_identity_map?
 => true
 [4] pry(main)>
```

EDIT:
As pointed out by @cbmanica, there are multiple places where `options` can be set. For example we could have:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/test_development
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
    op_timeout: 60
```

For the `options` that are set on the MongoDB database, they cannot be nested inside of `session`. See source for the [defaults](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/a8e4314b01bbfd37ddb026315a716d9f361386da/lib/mongoid/config.rb#L19-27).

Comment: The Mongoid documentation seems to directly contradict your assertion that `:options` shouldn't be nested in `:default`: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html.

Comment: @cbmanica There are multiple options that can be set, I edited my answer to highlight that. In the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) take a look at the "Anatomy of a Mongoid Config" section for examples of multiple options being set in multiple keys.